# Lightroom encountered an error when reading from the preview cache

Tags: lightroom-4, error

I have been having major issues with Lightroom recently. It took me 3hrs last night to export three sets of images because of this error.

The error comes at any point, during editing, during export, during import, on opening LR. It says that it will attempt to fix it when re-opening Lightroom but it doesn't work so I have to delete the preview cache file in explorer.

I have tried looking online for an answer to this but everyone just says delete the preview cache. This is fine but I get the error again shortly after and have to keep deleting it. I can't always delete it either, I sometimes have to go in via safe-mode to do it and obviously that takes a lot of time.

I really need a permanent fix to this issue. I would be tempted to upgrade to a later version but I'm worried that I may have the same problem.

Answer (score 1):

It may be worth trying Chkdsk, assuming you're running Windows. If you are persistently getting issues reading files, then it could be a hard disk issue.

Do you have your Lightroom catalogue on your internal hard disk or an external disk? You could try migrating everything to an external hard disk to see if that's the problem.

If it's on the internal hard disk, and if you're running Windows (it sounds like you are), you could go to a command prompt and run `chkdsk C: /F /R`, assuming C: is the drive letter. It may prompt you to restart the PC to run the check. Note, if you are using a Mac, there is a file system checker within the `Disk Utility` app where you can do a similar check for issues on the hard disk.

Is it a large catalogue of images? Can you test by creating a new catalogue and importing a batch of images into that new catalogue? Copy a bunch of folders in Pictures using Explorer to a Test directory, and create a new catalogue and import from there, and test that. By copying them to a test directory before importing it will ensure that you don't mess up any indexing or catalogue structure of your live catalogue.

You could also try uninstalling and reinstalling Lightroom, but in my mind this is less likely to have any effect.

Comment: Is the preview cache related to the catalogue? I have actually upgraded to a new drive to try and fix this. That didn't work and now it is located on an external drive which also doesn't work. I could run chkdsk I suppose. It is quite a large catalogue, which also seems corrupted for some reason because the backup never completes. I could try creating another catalogue but I don't know if it's an issue with the catalogue or the preview cache.

Comment: @connersz If you've swapped the disk out already then chkdsk probably wouldn't make any difference. I can't remember if there is some sort of catalogue repair tool? I think that is just the integrity check when you backup.